# Execute Raw SQL Queries in .NET Core application

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core

I want to execute some raw queries in the Backend(.Net Core) while having a number as a result.

I don't want to save it in the database .I just want to read it and show it in the front End (Angular)
Do i need to add a table and a model or just the service and the controller (like i did)?
I started with this:

```cs
var command = _db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ***.[dbo].[Employee]";
_db.Database.OpenConnection();
var result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: One (of many) options is to look at Dapper Micro ORM.  You'll write better code using a Framework over these inline sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, if this is that simple, you could use `Dapper` to achieve that.

so your code really becomes:

```cs
return await _db.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM ***.[dbo].[Employee]");
```

However, I would highly recommend to not do it and create a proper service contract and map your results to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well ty but i have found the solution :

```
  {
            string count = "" ;
            using (var connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "select AVG(ExchangeRate) from***.[dbo].[Devise]";
                    string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: This code is simply wrong - AVG returns a number, not a character. Using `char.TryParse` will result in a useless value, *especially* if `AVG` returns something like 1.5. All of this code is useless to begin with because `ExecuteScalar()` already returns a double or integer. All one needs is to cast the result to the correct type. Using ADO.NET is very well covered in the docs, tutorials and courses since 2002.

Comment: Wait.. what? You return a number, convert it to a string, to a char, to a number, to a string? wha the heck? why? If you're returning count, don't you want the number? why isn't it a number/integer all the way out? What's with all the voodooo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the model and dataset in your context

for example

```
public virtual DbSet<Employee> Content { get; set; }

public class Employee{ ...... }
```

then use

```
await _db.Employee.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM ***.[dbo].[Employee]");
```

Thanks